# Blank screen in game after automatic keypad lock in nokia S40

Tags: nokia, nokia-s40

After the automatic keypad lock, when I unlock it, there appears a blank white screen and after 3-4 seconds, the game field appears. Any ideas, how to avoid this behaviour? I want that the game canvas should be immediately displayed after the unlock.

Update:

Here is my startApp method:

```
public void startApp() {
   start();
}

 public void start() {

 instance = this;

display = Display.getDisplay(this);
display.setCurrent(myGame);
 }
```

Comment: Did you stop all game threads when the application was suspended? If not, there might be buffered repaint requests being processed.

Comment: Uptill now I  haven't use any thread.

Comment: Does you startApp method check if the application is being resumed? It should do a lot less things in this scenario.

Comment: Please see the updated part above.